# My GCLID code gets stripped when user is redirected to my Mobile Site

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, issue-tracking

I have a tracking issue due to GCLID gets stripped when users get redirected from our desktop site to our mobile site.  Let me know how we can get this fixed.

Here's a sample:

When a user is detected as using a mobile device, they are redirected automatically.  For example, if they were going to sitename.com/, they would instead end up on sitename.com/?___store=mobile2

The problem we are encountering is that we need certain query parameters from the original URL to be preserved when the redirect happens in order for tracking to work correctly.

If someone clicks a Google ad, they'll be taken to a URL with a gclid parameter appended by Google, for example: sitename.com/?gclid=ABC_123-abc
However, if the user is on a mobile device, they'll be redirected to sitename.com/?___store=mobile2.  As you can see, the gclid parameter is no longer present.

Let me know if you guys have any solution to this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The code that performs the redirection needs to preserve query parameters on the original request. In your case, it should also append an "&" and the ___store=mobile2 parameter.